# Tkinter row adder with entry text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, project

I'm having trouble extracting the location of "word" label y value and then adding a 30 to it to keep create another row for responses.

If anyways can help thank you :)

```
from tkinter import *

count = -1

def give():

    word = Label(window,text=response.get())
    word_location = word.place(x=100, y=140)
    response.destroy

    response.place(x=100, y=y+30)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("900x900")
window.configure(bg='lightgrey')

Title = Label(window, text='SCHEDULE', font=(20))
Title.pack(side=TOP)

Monday = Label(window, text='Monday', font=(10)).place(x=100,y=100)
response = Entry(window, width=10)
response.place(x=100, y=140)

button = Button(window, text='Enter', height=1, command=give).place(x=170, y=140)

window.mainloop()
```

The code in the give function is suppose to label out the repsonse I typed in. Place another entry field under it and then destroy the previous entry field whilst keeping the label text there. And it repeats

Supposely like

Monday

Maths

___ Enter

** and it keeps going after enter is clicked

I tried inputtin the word location in the place y value then + 30 but it didnt work.

I then tried to just do y + 30 but it's not specific.

Answer (score 1):

You created a button object but then also added the `.placed()` method making it to where the button object no longer had a variable to access it directly.

> button = Button(window, text='Enter', height=1,
> command=give).place(x=170, y=140)

Should be changed to:

```
button = Button(window, text='Enter', height=1, command=give)
button.place(x=170, y=140)
```

You can access the x, y coordinates of a tkinter object by using the `.winfo_y()` or `.winfo_x()` method. Then you can increment each new button by 30 pixels. You also do not need to destroy the widget when you could just clear the contents with `.delete(0, END)` and increment that object as well.

```
def give():
    word = Label(window, text=response.get())
    word.place(x=100, y=response.winfo_y())
    button.place(x=170, y=button.winfo_y()+30)
    response.place(x=100, y=response.winfo_y()+30)
    response.delete(0, END)
```